# can a UIImageView be warped? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm curious if it'd be possible to warp a UIImageView on the iPhone. I was thinking of stretching an image around a curve. Possible or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use texturemapping in OpenGL ES is probably the easiest way. 
Setting up a CoreGraphics context using Quartz is a little harder.